# Android notifications: have colors in small icon

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Since Lollipop, notification small icons are "masks" (only the alpha channel is used).
I can verify this in the project I am working on: previously we had a colorful small icon, and it worked well on 4.4- devices but appeared as a white square on 5.0+ devices.  (We updated the icon to fix this).

But now I see apps that manage to have colorful icons on 5.0+ devices!

**How do they do it?**

I realize I shouldn't even try to do that since the guidelines say the icon *should* be a white shape, but I am curious and would like to know how it is done.

I suspect this is related to the `targetSdk`, but didn't find any resources about it.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28387744/4193263).

Comment: @ByteHamster Thanks!  I suspected this. But it's very odd, because my project targets 19.  So according to this answer, I should never have had the issue in the first place!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: Hey @BoD. How did you convert the 'white square' to a proper icon on Android 5.0? I am unable to do this.