# White Icon in my Notification Bar in Nexus 5

Tags: android

Surprising my APP's icon comes up with white color icon in notification bar on my Nexus 5. This is only in Nexus 5.

[image]

There is a question already about this the answer shows I need have: target 20. Which I have tried already: Like below no difference.

```
defaultConfig 
{
    applicationId "com.cn.redquest"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.00"
}
```

Can somebody help me fix this?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `AndroidManifest.xml`. Maybe you need to define the version there.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop) is apparently the only solution so far

Comment: @ Tushar and @ByteHamster: Both Manifest and build.gradle have targetSDkVersion 20.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the target SDK to 20 means that you do not build your app for Android Lollipop. This will make your notification icon display all colors, but is not a long-term solution, since you will want to build for Lollipop (at least eventually).

At http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html you can read about that the white style is how notifications are meant to be displayed in Lollipop (SDK 21). Google also suggests using a custom bg color - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

I think a better solution is to actually provide the system with a silhouette icon, if the device is running Android Lollipop.

For instance:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
   .setAutoCancel(true)
   .setContentTitle("My notification")
   .setContentText("Look, white in Lollipop, else color!")
   .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
   .build();
```

And, in the getNotificationIcon method:

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useSilhouette = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useSilhouette ? R.drawable.ic_silhouette : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

Comment: Hey! what is R.drawable.ic_silhouette  here?

Comment: The last line is a check, where a silhouette image is returned for Android Lollipop or later. For older Android versions, the launcher icon is returned. R.drawable.ic_silhouette is thus a possible image resource in your project. You can return any image there...but it should be an image that works with a single color.