# Android icon generator for actionbar and notification not working (grey shape)

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-assets, android-icons

I found this [Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to generate icons. It works fine for the launcher icon but for action bar or notification icons it is not working. I put in my png file and want to generate the icons, but Asset Studio is only generating gray circles. Is there another tool to generate action bar and notification icons?

[image]

Comment: Having this problem also in Android studio. Somebody should find a way to overpass this problem.

Comment: This Demo
may help you out.

 http://androiduiux.com/2012/08/20/action-bar-icon-design-template-free-download/

Comment: yeah still not working....

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use a tool for creating generic icons in Asset Studio: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html.
To get it look like ActionBar Icon, you should make next actions:

1. Choose image
2. The size of image should stay at 24dip
3. Change padding to 4dip
4. Move foreground color thumb to 0%
5. That's it! Download .zip now.

The sizes of icons will be pretty the same as you can get them with ActionBar Icon Generator.

How it looks for me:
[image: icon generator screenshot]

Comment: but the sizes are wrong. and it doesnt work for notification icons.

Comment: I think it depends on your default image size. I've loaded 128x128 image, and the sizes were right for both tools. Anyways, you can adjust it for you needs, by dragging padding/size thumb.

Comment: What sizes do I use for notification image?

Comment: I used this tool and the settings above to generate tablayout icons, however, the icons end up above the tab text. I thought the icon was supposed to appear next to the tab text

Comment: I don't understand this answer @rom4ek. I am still facing the same issue trying to create Action Bar and Notifications icons.

Comment: Woks better than built-in AS 3.0 (beta)'s Image Asset Studio

Comment: its not working anymore can you update your answer i cant get it working

Comment: upvote for this line Move foreground colour thumb to 0% thanks man

Answer (score 9):

Use this instead https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html

Here demonstrating how to show the image:

1. upload your image
2. set the foreground color to 0, just like below

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225458/romtsn
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because your image is too complexe and the main problem is the "color" filter applied in AAS.

I had the same problem and I had to convert xxxhdpi xxhdpi etc. manually. If you work with Sketch (for example) it can be converted easily with a plugin (https://github.com/zmalltalker/sketch-android-assets)

hope it's help !

If you want to use AAR, like @rom4ek explained **"4. Move foreground color thumb to 0%"** this is the important part

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in feature of android studio to generate actionbar and notification icons.

Right click on `res` folder and `New > Image Asset`. You can choose `Launcher Icons`, `Action Bar Icons` or `Notification Icons` in the Asset Type.

**Update**:
You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop). It talks about white icon in notification.

Comment: even that is generating the same output as shown in the question. I think it has something to do with the image format.

Answer (score 1):

I use an own module 'icons' with a Gradle script to generate icons. This is a more automated way than the Assets Studio can provide up-to-now. The icon will be designed with Inkscape. See my [blog](http://christian-schulzendorff.blogspot.de/2015/12/including-icon-generation-into-android.html) for a detailed description. You find an Android Studio Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/chs8691/DemoIconCreator/tree/master/icons).

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem their is no issue with icon after Lollipop notification icon do not contains color icon it support flat,Silhouette icon supported.

- Either you can change target SDK to 20
- Or generate flat icon(icons8 is best option)

### Or

you should use a condition

```
  boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.icon_silhouette : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
```

Comment: Do not listen to this answer about setting target SDK to 20. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: Please read post carefully i mention two points which ever is best you can use it. I also no setting up target sdk to 20 is not best option

Answer (score 0):

after alot of search this is the solution:
the problem is you are adding an image with white background..
to convert the image to actionbar icon you have to load image with transparent background

Comment: good idea, but I checked in Photoshop and the surrounding space around my main icon is transparent (PNG)

Answer (score -1):

Android Studios 2.2 has an Image Asset Studio that you can use to generate your icons.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

Answer (score -7):

By default it will be grey color for any image. But you can customize it according to your color. Check below screenshot to select CUSTOM tab and then select color you want.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hä? I want it to generate my icon not any color. i dont want to have colors. i put in my own icon as png and i want to have my icons.

Comment: select css color of your icon and put it as custom color.

Comment: it is a png... there is no css color.

Comment: so what if its png, android uses png only

Comment: ... creating launcher icon: select image -> download icons -> everything okay. create action bar icons: select image -> download icons -> just gray circles...

Comment: can you show what your image is and what you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72034/discussion-between-virendrao-and-mulgard).

Comment: I have the same problem, I have a PNG icon in the colours I want, but when I add it to my app, it just becomes a gray circle. why?