# How to add an image to the "drawable" folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-drawable

I need to add an image to the `res/drawable` folder...

When I choose `new > Image Asset`, it comes out a dialog to choose `Asset Type`...

How can I add an image to `res/drawable` folder?

Comment: Why is it a problem if it is inside the `mipmap` folder? You just need to access it va `R.mipmap.[...]` rather than `R.drawable.[...]` Also, you can drag and drop images directly into the `drawable` folder in Android Studio - just make sure that your Project Structure is set to `Project`, and not `Android`, at the top left of the screen.

Comment: Android Studio uses mipmap folder to load launcher icon in project. as android says **It's best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device's current density. For example, an xxxhdpi app icon can be used on the launcher for an xxhdpi device.** take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24066445/1576416

Comment: See link:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700593/how-to-import-set-of-icons-into-android-studio-project][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700593/how-to-import-set-of-icons-into-android-studio-project

Comment: simply drag and drop to drawable folder

Comment: Hi Alan! As you can see my answer to this question is recommanded as a better one by comments and number of votes. You can accept it as the best answer if you think so too.

Comment: @kritika - I'm using Android Studio 3.0. It is not allowing me to drag and drop image files on `drawable` folder. It seems this behavior has changed in later versions.

Comment: Related post - [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10574363/465053)

Answer (score 429, accepted):

For **Android Studio 1.5**:

1. Right click on res -> new -> **Image Asset**
2. On **Asset type** choose **Action Bar and Tab Icons**
3. Choose the **image path**
4. Give your image a name in Resource name
5. <kbd>Next</kbd>-><kbd>Finish</kbd>

Update for **Android Studio 2.2**:

1. Right click on res -> new -> **Image Asset**
2. On **Icon Type** choose **Action Bar and Tab Icons**
3. On **Asset type** choose **Image**
4. On **Path** choose your image path
5. <kbd>Next</kbd>-><kbd>Finish</kbd>

The image will be saved in the /res/drawable folder.

**Warning!**
If you choose to use images other than icons in SVG or PNG be aware that it could turn grey if the image is not transparent. You can find an answer in comments for this problem but none of these are  verified by me because I never encountered this problem. I suggest you to use icons from here: [Material icons](https://material.io/icons/)

Comment: Hi. I followed the steps and it did save the image in that drawable folder. Now in my case, I´m not able to see the image preview the wizard presents when doing those steps. Anyone had that same problem?

Comment: @Fergara Try Invalidate Caches / Restart from File menu. If the problem persists open a new question. Maybe someone faced the same problem.

Comment: @Cristi This didn't work for me because a lot of the details of the image were [stripped away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860702/image-getting-destroyed-when-being-put-in-drawables-folder#34860702)

Comment: It doesn't work correctly for me either. A portion of the edge (all sides) are cropped out, and the image itself is re-sampled considerably. Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: This just doesn't work. The resulting images are just useless gray shapes.

Comment: Unless you are going to add to actionbar and it turns grey. Use as a launcher icon

Comment: @bradley4 It seems that the color problem appears only to some developers. I think it is from the size of the icon. Choosing Launcher Icons will put the icons in the wrong folder, not drawable. A similar problem about the grey background is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807121/android-icon-generator-for-actionbar-and-notification-not-working-grey-shape and more info about icons size here http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Comment: @markj is right. This method will change the icon color. Relevant information can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011070/how-to-set-the-color-of-icon-in-android-toolbar.

Comment: This doesn't works for raw images (not added as icons). See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367464/android-when-attempting-to-add-an-image-creates-a-blank-image

Comment: In case someone checked this response, the image should be transparent  to fix the gray issue

Comment: I think it's really strange that a regular image is categorised in Action Bar and Tab Icons.

Comment: This just doesn't work. The resulting images are just useless gray shapes. +1

Comment: @Osgux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047902/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-drawable-folder-in-android-studio/31069202?noredirect=1#comment73542663_31069202

Comment: Thanks! I saw a video when only copy the image to drawable it was really easy

Comment: So if you copy-pasted your pngs into your res directory, delete copy-pasta files and just do this solution instead. Worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @Osgux can u share the video

Comment: Why is dealing with images in Android still a nightmare? It's 2019!

Answer (score 198):

**For Android Studio 3.4+:**

You can use the new Resource Manager tab
Click on the `+` sign  and select `Import Drawables`.

From here, you can select multiple folders/files and it will handle everything for you.

[image: Resource Manager]

The result will look something like this:

[image: Resource Manager Picker]

Click the <kbd>import</kbd> button and the images will be automatically imported to the correct folder.

Comment: @abdu you can find about more at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager

Comment: This answer was the most beneficial for me as a new android developer using version 3.5.3

Comment: This is a great method, however the Next button in the wizard does nothing. Even when importing a single image the wizard will not continue past the first screen.

Comment: Never knew about this. Finally a better way to handle resource files in general. Thanks!

Comment: Where is Resource manager located though?

Comment: @GeneCode you can find it in the left tabs in Android Studio, if you read one of the previous comments you can see there's a link detailing everything about the Resource Manager.

Comment: If the Resource Manager would work reliably this would be the way to go, but maybe that's just the case for me (using v2021.3.1)

Answer (score 176):

Copy `*.png` image and paste to **drawable** folder.

After adding the image, you can use the added image asset in code:

You can either add image by using xml file

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_name" />
```

**OR** You can set image by using program:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(v);  
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

Comment: but that still doesnt solve the problem. The question here is about the mage truning grey or blank. When you copy the mage in the folder directly the image re-sizing is not done

Comment: you shouldnt have to resize the image ..android studio does it for you and puts it in various folders accordingly

Comment: I think you have to change to "project view mode", and then create a drawable-hdpi folder under res folder. Then, if you change to "android view mode" and try to paste a resource in drawable folder, ask you about where to put the image (I choose always drawable-hdpi)

Comment: @Terranology No need to create the folder first.  It will create the folder if it does not exist.  See [Kundan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007226/4515489).

Comment: can u explain what is v inside findViewById(v);  in ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(v);

Answer (score 74):

## Do it through the way Android Studio provided to you

Right click on the res folder and add your image as **Image Assets** in this way.
Android studio will automatically generate image assets with different resolutions.

You can directly create the folder and drag image inside but you won't have the different sized icons if you do that.

[image]

Comment: Which tool you use to make this?

Comment: It is a `gif` file format. You can get tons of tools on internet to create a `gif` file while performing various actions on your computer.

Comment: The problem is I have a size for each of the types hdpi, mdpi, etc and I don't want it to auto generate them from one image.

Comment: This doesn't generate the image with many colors correctly.

Answer (score 60):

For Example, I've to add `list.png` in drawable folder..

[image]

And now I'll paste it in drawable folder. Alternatively you can do it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>, as we programmers do it. :)

[image]

Answer (score 54):

It's very simple. Just copy your image and paste it in the drawable folder.
 One more thing. When you paste an image in the drawable folder, a popup window will appear asking for a folder name. Add xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi or mdpi according to your image, like in the image below:[image]

If you are still having problems, check out this link:
[Drawable folder in android studio](http://theandroidwarriors.blogspot.in/2017/03/android-studio-drawable-folders.html)

Comment: And this method automatically creates the folder if it does not exist.

Comment: Best and easiest method.

Answer (score 22):

You can just copy and paste an image file(.jpg at least) into your res/drawable. It worked for me!

Answer (score 16):

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Click on `res`
3. Right click on `drawable`
4. Click on `Show in Explorer`
5. Double click on `drawable` folder.
6. Copy your image file in it and rename as your wish.
7. Now write your image file name after `@drawable/` .

It will show the image you've selected.

Answer (score 12):

Install and use the Android Drawable Importer plugin:

https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin

Instructions on how to install the plugin are on that page. It's called "Android Drawable Importer" in the plugin search results.

Once installed:

1. right click on "res" folder and select New -> Batch Drawable Import
2. hit the + and select your source image
3. choose what resolution you want it considered and which other sizes to auto-generate for

Seems kind of ridiculous that Android Studio doesn't support this directly.

EDIT: But Xcode doesn't either so.... :-(

Comment: This is the only solution that allows you to use the image as intended. Nice and simple. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You need to use a third party plugin like AndroidIcons Drawable Import
to install this. 
Goto 
Android Studio > Prefrences > Plugins > and browse for  **AndroidIcons Drawable**
You can do things like

1. AndroidIcons Drawable Import
2. Material Icons Drawable Import
3. Scaled Drawable
4. Multisource-Drawable

Restart android studio. If you do not have the drawables folder created, create it by importing any image as **-"Action Bar and Tab Icons" & "Notification Icons",**. Then right clink on the file explorer and you can see 4 options in the **new** tab. Use any one according to your need.

Answer (score 9):

**Android Studio 3.0**:

1) Right click directory 'drawable'. 
2) Click on: Show in Explorer

Now you have an explorer opent with a few directories in it, one of then is 'drawable'.

3) Go in the directory 'drawable'. 
4) Place the image you want in there. 
5) Close the explorer again.

Now the image is in Android Studio under 'res/drawable'.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is to just drag and drop the image into the drawable folder. The important thing to keep in mind if you are using Android Studio 2.2.x version make sure you are in **PROJECT VIEW** else it will not allow to drag and drop the image.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**[Tutorial Source Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/android-how-to-add-new-images-in-android-studio-project-3-2/)**

**Android Studio 3.2**

**Blazingly fast :P**

[image]

Just Copy and Paste in this folder

Answer (score 4):

My way of exporting/importing image assets. I use Sketch design.

**Step 1. Sketch: export using Android preset**

[image: Sketch]

**Step 2. Finder: Go to the export folder > <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**
[image: Finder]

**Step 3. Finder: Go to your project's /res folder > <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> > Apply to all > Merge**
[image: Finder]

OK, the images are in your project now.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple

1) just copy your images and paste in drawable folder.

2)  when you paste image(for eg"mdpi) in drawable folder a popup window  will  appear asking folder name add  -mdpi .

3)Do it for all(hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi).

I just added one link that you can check out if have any doubt.

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/07/android-studio-drawable-folders.html

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, you can go through following steps to add an image to drawable folder:

1. Right click on **drawable** folder
2. Select Show on **Explorer**
3. Paste image you want to add

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your images and select drawable then on the option of Paste or press shortcut ctrl v. images are added

Answer (score -1):

**Example without any XML**

Put your image `image_name.jpg` into `res/drawable/image_name.jpg` and use:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
        setContentView(imageView);
    }
}
```

Tested on Android 22.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the image then paste it to drawables in the resource folder of you project in android studio.Make sure the name of your image is not too long and does not have any spacial characters.Then click SRC(source) under properties and look for your image click on it then it will automatically get imported to you image view on you emulator.

Answer (score -1):

Adding images to the drawable folder is pretty simple.
Just follow these steps:

1. Download the required image and save it on desktop.
2. Now, go to Android Studio and right click on **drawable** inside **res.**
3. On right clicking you will see **'Show in Explorer'** or **'Reveal in Finder'.**
4. Click on 'Show in Explorer' or 'Reveal in Finder' and then drag or simply copy your downloaded image into drawable folder.

**Your image will be saved inside drawable and you can use it.**

Answer (score -2):

go to
https://hotpot.ai/icon-resizer
and resize your stock png(!) image to a batch as zip.
Put e.g. **_** before their names ( otherwise it seems wont be accepted by A S (who knows why) )

Then go to AS's **Resource Manager** on the left panel and then hit  `+` on its top-left and **import images** you've gotten one-by-one.
Dont use unofficial plug-ins.

Comment: It generated terrible names for images. Also, why not use unofficial plug-ins? what else we can do if Google does not provide any tools for this

Comment: @George Shalvashvili  e.g. you can lose your employer

Answer (score -3):

new > image asset > asset TYPE.  works for me very well. thanks.

Answer (score -6):

In Android Studio

1. Select Drawable folder, do **Ctrl N**  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOLOd.png)
2. Select **Image asset**
3. Select **Action Bar & Tab icons** in asset type
4. Click Next
5. Select size
6. You're done!