# Theare aren't different drawable folders on Android Studio

Tags: android, image, size, drawable

I m trying to integrate different image size in my app but the problem is that in Android Studio there are not the drawable-Idpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi folders.
I ve checked already other threads and the answers were that I just need to skip into the Project view instead of the Android one. But the results are the same. There is just one generale folder called drawable

[image]

[image]

And if I try to add another resource folders the drawable is missing.

[image]

Comment: Never seen those mipmap folders, in my projects they're called drawables-mdpi and so on...

Comment: You can create manually.

Comment: Check below link this question is answered already http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007226/5039767

Comment: Man this post is like an year old.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just create a new folder:

Right click 'res' folder --> New --> Android Resource Directory.

In the wizard, select drawable as 'Resource Type'. And then 'Density' from the resource qualifiers.

With regard to the 'mipmaps' folders, Android now prefers app icons in these folders because it can use an icon in a different density to the screen density.

More about mipmaps here: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: So do you mean that I should insert my images in the mipmpas folders (even if it is a bg?)

Comment: Notice the list of items scrolls - scroll up and you should see it above 'interpolator'

Comment: Thanks for advice. it's worked for me but before doing this project view should be changed project files or projects view.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem before.
I fixed it by downloading an icon that i wanted from http://www.icons4android.com/

now this site provides all the drawable-Idpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi folders for download for each icon they have, I just highlighted all the drawable-Idpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi folders, copied them, and then pasted them to android studio res folder.
(I did this in android view)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create folder same as drawable, drawable-hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi ... etc

Its look like

[image]

But when you see source code using

[image]

[image]

Add images in draweble its ask you in which folder you want to add(copy n past images in studio)

[image]

You can directly creat folder in res its also work...