# Image getting destroyed when being put in drawables folder

Tags: android, image

I have the following image that I intend to use in a game:

[image]

When I use "Add new Image Asset" and add this image as a "Action Bar and Tab Icon"

All the black parts of the image are replaced with white so the image looks like this when it is drawn on the canvas:

[image]

Why is the image getting destroyed and how do I fix it?

I thought about putting the image as a "Launcher Icon" but that didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding it to a drawable folder instead? The Image Assert importer will scale down images to the make them the correct size for icons, which is probably not what you want anyway

Comment: I am also facing similar problem. Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scaletype` property in `ImageView` which helps you to manage the image inside `ImageView`.