# Back to previous activity arrow (button?)

Tags: android

I just have a little question here. How can I make this arrow to back to previous activity? I mean, I know how to code it, but i can't find this arrow. Is it something, that is in e.g. android studio or is it something that i have to make by myself?[image]

Comment: go to new and create new drawable from it.

Comment: show your code so that we can find out what is the wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image to the "drawable" folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047902/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-drawable-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? do you want to change the default drawable?

Comment: I want to add it, cause if i launch my main activity and go to second activity i want to have this arrow like on pic that can bring me back to main activity. Now I have only button but this arrow looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, here is what I suggest:

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />
```

Activity:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // back button pressed
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to back your previous Activity.

Code is Here :

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show  top back arrow you have to enable the display home button `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and you will get the arrow click event at `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){

       // do your task on arrow click

       return true;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```