# Android: Can't drag image into res drawable

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-image

I am suddenly unable to drag images into res/drawables, it shows a redbox/outline preventing me from doing so. Has anyone else encountered this before? I was able to add images via dragging with no problem earlier in the day!

Android studio 3.1.1 build #AI-173.4697961, 4/3/18 on macOS High Sierra

[here is an example with a new android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS3nV.jpg)

Comment: try adding it to a *qualified* directory, for example `drawable-xxhdpi` or `drawable-nodpi`

Comment: I am new to Android and just following a tutorial I am seeing online, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: just create the directories in Finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below Step:

If You want to paste a image in Folder then see below Step:

1. Go in your machine where you save your project
2. Open your **Project Folder**
3. Now select a folder **app > src > main > res >**
4. Now you can see hear 7 Drawable Folder
5. In some folder you can paste your **Image**
6. Folder Name : **drawable-hdpi** , **drawable-mdpi** , **drawable-xhdpi** , **drawable-xxhdpi** , **drawable-xxxhdpi** .
7. Paste Your Folder in above Folder

If you want to copy and paste a Image in android Studio Drawble Folder then U just see Right corner on Android Studio

**Change app to Project** see below image for batter understanding:

[image]

Now Go to the down and see the all drawable Folder and paste your image one by one See below image :

[image]

If You want to paste image using other Technic then follow link [How to add an image to the "drawable" folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047902/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-drawable-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: I only see 4 folders under res, drawable, layout, mipmap, and values

Comment: yes i was able to find the folder, thanks for the help Mohammad, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The drawable folder is supposed to have only XML drawables try adding `drawable-hdpi` and putting the image there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out a noob, turns out I was trying to add it in the wrong subdirectory of the android studio project! Thanks again for your patience guys.