# How do I add icons into the android:drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences

I'm putting icons next to options in the `preferences.xml` file. I was looking for a few icons to represent specific options I had but couldn't find them. So I want to know how I can add icons so that they will appear here `android:icon=@android:drawable.`

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047902/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-drawable-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: You want them in the system namespace (`android:`)? That's not possible unless you run your own proprietary Android version.

Comment: @Henry Sorry I couldn't understand his question...

Comment: @TheB Glad to have helped :-) if you are happy with that I think you should be able to mark this question as a duplicate of that other one?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the drawable folder, then select new and then vector asset. Either you can use clipart which includes many icons, or you can just select local svg and can add your own icons locally from your device.
Then click on next. In next step, you can also see the location where the icons will be added.

I hope this will help.