# Add png image to drawable keeps giving me a gray square

Tags: android, android-studio

So I right click on my drawable folder, say add image asset, go to action bar and tab icons and then try to import a png.  I have tried 4 different png and for every single one, all that shows up is a gray box

Stackoverflow won't let me show one of the images I was trying but they were all just pngs

Comment: Your question has been answered right here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047902/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-drawable-folder-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe png image size is too large, you can convert it to webp format and load it to drawable (For this, right-click png file last option is  'convert to webp format').