# Loading up image when a string is used

Tags: android

for example

```
     public static String[] dogs = {
                "White dog",
                "brown dog"
               }
```

is it possible to load up an image when "white dog" is called/used?

Comment: If I understand your question, try to add a getter method to your class, and every time this getter is called with "brown dog" parameter, for example, load you image

Comment: @MatanKintzlinger i think its gonna work, gonna try it out

Comment: sorry if my question is quite broad, it was just a sudden thought, just had to ask about it

Comment: `if(dogColor.equals( "White dog")) {loadWhiteDogPicture();}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load images in Android Studio in the fashion you want to, you need to do the following:

1. [Add the images to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047902/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-drawable-folder-in-android-studio) (inside the drawable folder)
2. Put all the images inside the array (I.E. [R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2]
3. Then you can access those elements based upon the logic you need