# Unable to Load Images on Android device (v. 4.4.4) from Android Studio Project due to an Inflate Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, imageview, inflate-exception

I am faced with the following error which is displayed in Logcat:

```
01-17 10:31:45.981 317-317/com.example.socialskillstraining E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.socialskillstraining, PID: 317
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialskillstraining/com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07008a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2329)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:209)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-17 10:35:01.211 534-534/com.example.socialskillstraining E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.socialskillstraining, PID: 534
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialskillstraining/com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07008a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2329)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:209)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-17 10:51:26.963 1198-1198/com.example.socialskillstraining E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.socialskillstraining, PID: 1198
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialskillstraining/com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07008a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2329)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:209)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.socialskillstraining.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The odd thing is that the images load both on my emulator as well as on another android device (running on v. 9), so the issue seems to be with the old android version. The following is the image view which is causing the above exception:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
```

The image which I am trying to load (logo) is stored in the drawable folder. I am quite lost as I find it strange how the android version could be impacting the success of loading images into my application.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `logo` a vector drawable?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann it is a .png file

Comment: How did you add the your image in a drawable folder?

Comment: @MaxShwed downloaded it from online and then copy-pasted into the drawable folder

Comment: Ok, try to add images in much more correctly way, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069202/12337593

Comment: are your `logo.png` in the main `drawable` folder or any other `drawable` folder ex `drawable-xxhdpi` ,etc

Comment: @MohammedAlaa in the main drawable folder. I do not have any other drawable folders.

Comment: have you tried to use `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I first uninstalled and reinstalled the application on the device. Then, I imported the images as hdpi files.