# How to add custom drawable assets in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use the [quick_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_actions) package in my flutter project. In their docs, it is said that icon can only be a `native drawable (android)`.

How exactly can I add my own custom drawables to my flutter project and use them?

[image: Reference]

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069202/11118209?