# How to set notification icon in Lollipop?

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-5.0-lollipop

I can not get an app_icon in the notification bar.
I want to set my app icon in notification icon.
How can I do this?

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(icon);

I got White icon instand of app icon

Comment: Post your code what you have tried yet.

Comment: did you look it out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, mainly it happens with the issue of not suporting sizes. hope this might help.

```
Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("DPD News")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.YOURICON_SMALL) // this is the icon that show in notification are before drage down, small icon. this has to be 25px X 25px
                .setLargeIcon(LARGE_ICON) // i have use the same sizes of ic_launcher to this
                .setContentText("MESSAGE")
                .setContentIntent(pi)  // pending intent if needed
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
```