# how to set status bar icon for notification in android 5

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I send notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
      mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.smalNotificationBackground));
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentText(text);
     mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        int mNotificationId = i+900;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

When it happen in status bar I see just white square, how to set my app icon?
When screen is lock, notification is ok, with my Icon.

Comment: I think your icon is transparent. please check icon

Comment: @Destro In application list on the phone I see my icon

Comment: create transparent notification icon

Comment: @NandakishoreShetty Is it the same with app icon or notification icon is separately?

Comment: create separate icon for notification

Comment: @NandakishoreShetty thank you for answers! How then setup this icon in code?

Comment: mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);  - here you can set ur new icon

Comment: what is your target version ..I think its greater than 19? Change the target version to 19 and try ,it should work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop