# Android, Lollipop notification icon is white in the notifications tray

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I managed to get rid of the white icon in the status bar using the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Now, the notification icon is fine on the status bar but is white in the notifications tray. I tried to set the large icon, but the small icon still shows as white. is there a solution to this problem?
 possible solution is to show the large icon without the small icon, is this possible?
I don't like the solution of setting the target sdk version to pre-lollipop.

Comment: As some answers out there says, this is not a bug, it is a feature. In Lollipop the icons in notification tray and the icon itself in the notification is meant to be white by design specs of material design. Look at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Comment: You can set the background of the notification icon (what you see when you pull down). Is it impossible to set the color of the icon in teh tray?