# Not showing push notification icon in the top bar when using parse on emulator

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Im using parse to send push notifications, The problem is that when I send push notifications the top bar in the emulator shows only a white square and not the icon, when I get the notification on the real device, samsung s6, samsung nexus, this is working great(I have tested only on this two devices).[image: the white square is the wrong push image]

any ideas?

Comment: Please specify the emulator android version.

Comment: The emulator is from genymotion,API 21, android 5.0.0, also some one reported this on  LG G2 D802

Answer (score 0):

Due to the new design changes introduced in Android 5.0, you need to use to the notifications only white icons. You can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#guidelines

The system will automatically convert your icons to white. My suggestion is to you create white notification icons.

You can find more information about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207365/3482000