# How to show notification icon in colored one in android lollipop version

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

I'm making one application, notification icon in Lollipop is showing while, for my knowledge I know that Lollipop shows that icon in white color, but I saw that other application is showing icon in colored one. How to do that? I want my icon to be colored in Lollipop. If anyone knows a solution please let me know.

[image: I have attached image for notification icon]

Comment: I think you will find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: ya i have gone through the link, but not able to find solution

Comment: ya i have gone through the link but am not able to find solution, please see the image i have displayed above, how they done notification icon in colored one in lollipop

Comment: Please, What is the name of the app? I want to decompile to see the source code. If possible, post the link. Tanks :D

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `targetSdkVersion` in gradle or manifest file below 21, the notification icon will be colorful. (From sdk level 21 there is a white filter on the notification icon.)

Gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API Level 21 or higher, you should not be using such a notification icon, since it is against Lollipop's Notification design guidelines.

**This is how notification icon looks in Lollipop and above**

[image]

There will be a single icon and you can call *setColor()* method to set the desired color to the surrounding. In this image which is RED.

But if you are not considering it right now. Then you should lower the *targetSdkVersion* below **21** in your *build.gradle* file.

```
targetSdkVersion 20
```

***So it's not recommended to show the notification icon colored as the one you mentioned.***

Comment: I'm appreciate for your response, i too know that in lollipop notification icons looks white, i have seen that some other application is showing in colored one, how it is possible?? i have mentioned screen short also which taken in lollipop phone

Comment: That's by using a target sdk lesser than Lollipop's.