# Notification icon is white on the notification tray

Tags: java, android, codenameone

My app icon on the notification tray became white on android 5.
I have seen this [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop) , but how can I change it on my codenameone app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to place a 24x24 icon named "ic_stat_notify.png" under the src/ folder of the app.
The icon can be white with transparency areas.
The build server picks up this image and uses it as the notification icon if found on the project.