# Adding android push notification icon in codenameone app

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, codenameone, parse4cn1

I'm using the [parse4cn1](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1) to enable push notifications for my cn1 app (with a hosted parse server called [back4app](https://www.back4app.com/)).  I want to add a custom icon for the notification tray in Android, and I need to add a line to the `<application>` section of the manifest.xml file:

`<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>`

Where do I put the png file within the cn1 project structure?

Comment: Codename One supports such icons in the native push as far as I recall. No idea about parse4cn1. Either way I added the tag to parse4cn1 so this will draw the right attention

Comment: This is not a parse4cn1 question per se: It's an issue of where CN1 expects resources specified in the manifest to be placed in the folder hierarchy. I searched a bit online but couldn't find a clear answer. @ShaiAlmog: Can you provide a pointer?

Comment: PS: Adding the meta data tag should work using [build hint](http://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) `android.xapplication`

Comment: Should have scrolled down to https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#build_hints_in_cn1libs you can just add the two files to the cn1lib. We discussed this in the blog too a while back https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deprecations-simplified-cn1lib-installs-theme-layering.html

Comment: Sorry, Shai, I didn't understand your answer.  I need the png file to be added to the res/drawable-xhdpi directory in the android source.  Is there are a way to do this without just downloading the project's android source code and building myself?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: That's unrelated to us. We support our standard push notification API I have no idea what parse uses.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog the original question is where to place a file within the project structure so that it will be placed in a drawables directory in the native Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995371/notification-icon-is-white-on-the-notification-tray/34995372#34995372) on SO by Hen Fishbein, one of the co-founders of CodenameOne, but for some reason it was very hard for me to find, so I'm reiterating it:

Put a file named ic_stat_notify.png in the src/ folder of the project.  The icon should conform to the Android guidelines for such icons, as stipulated [in the docs](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html).  The official recommendation is to add 5 differently-sized icons for the various screen density buckets, all of them being 24 dp, with a 22 dp area for the icon and 2 dp of padding.  The CodenameOne project only allows one file, so I recommend making it 72 pixels, which corresponds to the *xhdpi* bucket.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is currently unsupported but is probably something we should support as we do support it for sound files and XML files. I suggest filing an RFE in the [issue tracker](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) asking for this.