# Blank icon using Ionic on Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

We executed `ionic resources` and `ionic run android`. We are using the [PushNotification plugin (version 2.1.1)](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324). The following code is used for handling push notifications:

```
pushNotification.register(
                    function(data) {}, function(error) {},
                    {
                        "senderID": "***",
                        "ecb": "window.onAndroidNotification",
                    });
```

Now when we send a push notification to the device, we see a white square on Android as the icon of the push notification. When using Phonegap Build instead of building the application with Android, we get the app icon.
How can we set the app icon as push notification icon in Ionic (without modifying files in `resources/android/drawable/...`)?

Kind regards,
Kevin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: As mentioned, I am using Ionic which is Javascript based. I can unfortunately not modify Android files :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I start using this plugin, you can control the size and type of the icon for the notification.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md

Comment: Thanks a lot! Luckily it has more than enough documentation :-).