# Notification icon is round white instead of application icon in lollipop

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-5.0-lollipop

I have generated a local notification by this following code.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("message")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
    .build();



private static int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.icon_loli : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

where icon icon_loli is 16*16 white icon. still for the api version below 21, it works very fine but on lollipop & above it will show a notification as in image below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `setSmallIcon()`, and with the material design it is only black and white because the main purpose is to show uniformed icon into the top bar. If you want your logo, you will have to use [`setLargeIcon()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Icon%29) like:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("message")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
    .build();
```

Comment: setLargeIcon() take the full scale logo of app as in api lvl below 20?

Comment: No problem. You should have use Large icon and Small icon from the beginning. The small for the status bar (design recommended to have a white icon, but before lollipop you can use whatever you want. But since Lollipop, the OS forces you to display only white small icon). The Large icon will keep the colored icon you input.

Comment: I have placed white icon. 16x16. it show me that notification icon as in image above, this is what my question was

Comment: The small icon is use as the image you've shown because there is no large icon.

Comment: what is recommended wxh for notification icon, with transparent bg?

Comment: Check the design guide line for more information https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior

Comment: You don't need the `.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())` since it is the default behaviour.