# Android notification icon color is not changed to grey when background color is light

Tags: android, colors, notifications, icons

I know this question is exactly the same than this question

[Android notification icon color is not changed when background color is white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017672/android-notification-icon-color-is-not-changed-when-background-color-is-white)

However I could not find any solution in the answers/comments of this question.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: have u found the solution?

Comment: No, however I now use unicolor icon (color of my app) that works both on light and dark background. I tried on several Android devices and it was always working. Hope it helped a bit !

Answer (score 1):

Use a **mipmap** icon instead of a drawable icon and put it in xxxhdpi-mipmap folder. 
The icon will automatically adjust its color if the background is white

Comment: Thanks bro. You saved me.

Comment: what about if background color is not white?