# Android Color Notification Icon

Tags: java, android, colors, push-notification, android-notifications

I'm working on an app where I create a notification for the user. I want the icon to appear as white when it's in the status bar, but colored blue when it's being displayed in the drop down notification menu. Here's an example of the same thing being done by the Google Store app.

White notification in status bar:

[image]

Colored notification in drop down menu:

[image]

How can I replicate this? What properties do I have to set?

**Edit:**
Here's my current code - I made the image all white with a transparent background, so it looks fine in the status bar, but in the notification drop, the image is still the same white color:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder() {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(mainActivity)
                .setDeleteIntent(deletedPendingIntent)
                .setContentIntent(startChatPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.skylight_notification)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mainActivity, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentTitle(mainActivity.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(mainActivity.getString(R.string.notification_prompt));
    }
```

Comment: I was able to solve this problem - please see my answer below.

Comment: For those who is using admin sdk for notification!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950197/4394594

I don't know entirely what the problem was, but by putting the huge png that I was using for the icon into the this tool https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_skylight_notification
and by placing the generated icons it gave into my mipmap folder, I was able to get the `setColor(...)` property to work correctly.

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent way too long trying to figure out why my notification icon was still appearing white in the notification banner, and finally with that tool my notification icon correctly uses the color in the banner (while still being white in the status bar)

Comment: To everyone who ended up here and is genering icons with photoshop (or any other graphic design tool). Don't use CMYK mode! Use RGB when creating/exporting an icon - it helped in my case

Comment: I used this tool, my image is a pure white transparent PNG and I made sure it's in the RGB color space, but `SetColor` still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: To anyone still stuck, try downscaling the image. A 72x72 icon didn't work for me, but 48x48 did.

Answer (score 43):

For firebase nofitications sent from console you just need to add this in your manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/white_logo" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/custom_color" />
```

Where white_logo is your app white logo, and custom_color is the color you want to have the icon and text colored.

More details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Added the icon as suggested by the "Oblivionkey3" but after  `adding <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/custom_color" />`  icon color set to custom. Before this icon color was grey on Andriod Oreo notification (Status bar was icon being displayed in white).

Comment: what is `custom_color` ? and how to set it?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging#customize-default-notification

Comment: @mukesh.kumar, custom_color is any color you want to use. you just need to declare it in colors file

Answer (score 29):

Here is what I did for my app ...

```
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    Log.d(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Displaying Notification");
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    mBuilder.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("EarthQuakeAlert");
    mBuilder.setContentText("It's been a while you have checked out earthquake data!");
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Sample With Color:

[image]

Sample without Color:
[image]

Answer (score 15):

When building the notification, you can set the color and the icon. **If your icon is a pure white image**, it'll apply the color for you in the correct spots.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val notificationId = 10 // Some unique id.

    // Creating a channel - required for O's notifications.
    val channel = NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
            "Channel human readable title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    // Building the notification.
    val builder = Notification.Builder(context, channel.id)
    builder.setContentTitle("Warning!")
    builder.setContentText("This is a bad notification!")
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.skull)
    builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
    builder.setChannelId(channel.id)

    // Posting the notification.
    manager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately all that changing the color did for me was change the color of the text next to the image in the notification drop down, not change the color of the image at all.

Comment: Are you using a pure white icon as your small icon? It should colour that when it needs to.

Comment: It's pure white with a transparent background, and it's saved as a png

Comment: I edited my post, and tested some code on O, and the code above works for making my icon and text both my `color_primary` when pulled down, and just pure white when not. Hopefully that'll help more.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I managed to find solve this using another method which I just added to this page.

Comment: Cool, glad you could figure it out.

Comment: God bless you Advice-Dog. This was the answer I needed tonight.

Answer (score 6):

I might be late to the party but all above answers are not relevant or deprecated.

[image]

You can achieve this easily by using `setColor` method of `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Example:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "whatever_channel_id")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification) //set icon for notification
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.pink))
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText("Notification Message!")
```

Now it will show notification as pink color

**Note:**
If you are using firebase then the color won't be seen directly. You have to add this in manifest file.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/pink" />
```

Comment: They should have called "setColor" "setIconColor" instead and it woud have been obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change color and title name as per gmail and twitter in Push notification or inbuilt notification then you need to add these lines in notification.

```
 builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.skull)
    builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
```

First line used for icon and in second line you need to define color

Answer (score 1):

For those who is using admin sdk like me follow this add these in manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/pink" />
```

in your message payload add the icon name color You want!

```
var payloadImage = {
    notification: {
      title: data.title,
      image: `${data.body}`,
      sound: "default",
      color: "#b75061",
    },
  };
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. simple solution that i have found

1. Right click on **drawable>new>image assets**
2. select icon type to Notifications icon
3. Play around with the dimensions according to your needs.
   [image]

```
  NotificationManagerCompat compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white))
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 500, 100, 5000})
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(message))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setVibrate(vibrate)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DrawableCompat.setTint(int drawable);` of the drawable before setting the drawable.
And do `mutate()` the drawable otherwise the color tint will be applied to every instance of that drawable

Comment: I'd advise against this or else you'll have a coloured icon within the status bar.

Answer (score -1):

Create your Notification Icon using **"Asset Studio"** available in the Android Studio itself (Right Click res folder and New > Image Asset)

[Android Studio New Image Asset Studio Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ9R8.png)

Then set the color for notification

```
int color = Color.argb(255, 228, 14, 18);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setColor(color)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for an icon color or icon for notification on the right side, then follow the steps:

1. create the res folder with sub-folders like drawable,drawable-hdp,drawable-xhdp..etc. [You can create this folder by [Notification icon generator](https://icons.learnpainless.com/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=notification_icon)
2. After adding your folders, inside you will get a file with a .png image.

[image]

3. the drawable folders contains one .png file each, repleace the png file with you logo, or you can use any image there with same older name like
   if your older icon name is "notification_icon.png", then rename the new image with "notification_icon.png".
4. That's it. This will only work, if your logo is coming like black-and-white.

Thank you.