# Set color for app name text in notification (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to set color for app name text that appears on top of notification. How to change the color to green or blue from grey?

[image: I am looking for something like below, for whatsapp it is green but for my app it is grey]

Comment: try using customView notification

Answer (score 7):

Just set the color of your notification (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874836/364388):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
...
builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_notif_color));    
manager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
```

Comment: this is working for notification small icon but not for the app name.

Answer (score -1):

Find TextView by its it and use **SetTextColor** method to set the color. ex. as following.

```
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
var dialog = builder.Show();
int textColorId = Resources.GetIdentifier ("alertTitle", "id", "android");
TextView textColor = dialog.FindViewById<TextView> (textColorId);
textColor?.SetTextColor (Color.DarkRed);
```

Comment: This doesn't apply to notifications