# Colorful FCM Notification icon

Tags: android

I was just wondering how could you set a **multi colored notification icon** using **FCM** since right now i'm using the snippet below in `AndroidManifest.xml` to color it and its only possible to have one color.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_default" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able to define the color at the time of showing the notification refer the below link

[Android Color Notification Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874742/android-color-notification-icon)

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
I've already seen the information in the link but if im not mistaken they are doing the same thing ive done for FCM and this will only set **one** color for the icon but I want to be able to have a multi-colored notification icon in the notification tray.