# Android - Notification icon color not affected by setColor

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I'm showing a notification in my app. I would like the small icon to be white in the status bar but another color (greenish) in the notification itself, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874742/android-color-notification-icon).

I'm using a 72x72, pure white, transparent, RGB-gamma-color-space PNG file as the icon:

[image: white bell icon]

This is how it appears in the status bar:

[image: status bar with white icon]

But it's still white in the notification itself (even though the app title gets the correct color):

[image: notification with white icon]

This is the code I use to display the notification:

```cs
using AndroidX.Core.App;

var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MY_CHANNEL")
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_notification_alert)
    .SetContentTitle("Test1")
    .SetContentText("This is a test")
    .SetColor(GetColor(Resource.Color.colorPrimary));

NotificationManagerCompat.From(this).Notify(777, builder.Build());
```

I already tried moving the icon to the drawable folder, the mipmap folder and using the tool mentioned in [the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874742/android-color-notification-icon). I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0.0 installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downscaling the icon to exactly 48x48 pixels suddenly made the correct color appear.
I still don't understand this undocumented behavior.