# How to change color of notification icon on tray?

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications

I have added a custom notification to my app. It is white and appear normally on the status bar. I changed the color of the notification, but the icon remais white, so in the tray it won't appear. Is there a way to change the color of the icon on the notification tray?

[image]

[image]

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_e_ai_notif_icon" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883564/8133524

Comment: edit your `colors.xml`file to include to include a `colorPrimary` part. Take a look here: https://medium.com/nonstopio/change-the-firebase-notification-icon-in-a-flutter-245b7f7dc546