# How do I set the notification icon to a specific color?

Tags: java, android, android-notification-bar

I am trying to set notification icon which I generated using Android Image Asset. Generated image has just white color and some transparent part.

I pasted here piece of code here. Which doesn't reflect same color what I set in my code.
See my code. and please provide solution if possible.

My piece of code looks like this:

```
Notification inboxStyleNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFcmListenerService.this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_status_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(anImage)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setChannelId(transactions_chnl_id)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_light))
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
```

yellow_light code is: `#FFC107`
But when it reflects with `R.drawable.noti_status_icon` it doesn't reflect with exact `yellow_light` color.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

first, remove this code part

```
.setLargeIcon(anImage)
.setStyle(inboxStyle)
```

then generate a notification icon like this, select an image, set the yellow color there, click next, and finish. it will generate an icon with a yellow color and icon name to noti_status_icon.

[image]

[image]

then use the below code

```
Notification inboxStyleNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFcmListenerService.this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_status_icon)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setChannelId(transactions_chnl_id)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: When I generate using vector asset, in task bar I get colored icon too which is not my requirement, very rare apps do this.

In my case I generate using Image Asset by selecting notification icon option. And then adding color using .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_light)) in my code.
Problem is, it working but not reflecting with exact color what I was passing.

Comment: generate 2 icons,
1 for notification with vector asset and yellow color and
2nd for taskbar with Image Asset.
and use them according to ur requirements.
so your problem will solved.

Comment: please share taskbar code, there you can change icon color with tint command.

Comment: Here by taskbar I meant for Top status bar. For that no need to set it separately. It takes icon from the above code itself when we write .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_status_icon). It shows with color when we write .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_light)),  in expanded view of notification and black and white in top status bar. My issue was, It is not showing exact color as set but somewhat darker.

Comment: Please test it other phone too. some mobiles shows notification icon black and white by default I have seen. Your code may be ok, the issue was with phone.

Comment: yeah that is true. But some mobile like google pixel shows notification icon with color in expanded view. And that color is not exactly the same which I passed.

Comment: ook understand. Now tell me that is it taking yellow color but not that yelow which you want or it is not taking yellow color at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950197/4394594

Remember one thing, your notification icon does not contain any background, because the icon with a background not work properly in the notification icon.

I don't know entirely what the problem was, but by putting the huge png that I was using for the icon into the this tool
[https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_skylight_notification](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_call_white)
and choose your image ( with large dimension ), download the resource and copy them to your project, I was able to set the setColor(...) property to work correctly.

and finally set the notification icon using .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ICON_NEW_NAME)