# Android 6.0 marshmallow big picture notification blank images

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

While creating `NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle` notifications in Android, we have noticed that many times, the BigPicture comes out to be blank/white.

Salient features of this problem are:

1. Happens MOSTLY on Android 6.0 devices, while the same notification is rendered correctly on pre-6.0 devices. (Have seen this problem occurring once or twice on pre-6.0 devices as well though)
2. When I debug it, the debugger states that the Bitmap is invalid (Displays the images correctly for images that load on Marshmallow devices)
3. One issue that we were able to find with our images was that some of these had an alpha channel. Once we fixed this, the number of blank images reduced (However this number is still not zero).

I'll edit this as and when I find more details about the problem. Meanwhile, if there is a guideline for setting this image (such as there should not be any alpha channel etc.), then please share here.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: @R.Zagórski: I am talking about the Big Picture. Not the small icon. Thanks for the look-in! :)

Comment: I have come across same thing Man. Our case the image was a .gif which was failing in 6.0 and 6.0.1 as I have seen. JPEGs are working well in this case for me. 
Try changing to JPEG if you can till there is some solution for this.?

Comment: Facing the same issue! Any leads?

Comment: @nipun.birla What Muhammad Riyaz said is actually correct. We eventually had to resort to using JPEGs of small(ish) sizes. Wasn't still a 100% solution, but I guess it's better than nothing.