# Android notification icon still colored

Tags: android, push-notification

As it is known, since Android Lollipop the notification icon in the top bar is white, c.f. here [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop).

Interestingly, this does not happen in my app. This is my code

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setGroup(NEW_RESULT_GROUP)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

`R.mipmap.logo` is a coloured logo I use as starter icon. I expected to see a white version of it, or a white square, but what appeared was the full logo in all its colours.

Why does that happen?

**EDIT:** 
I use the Firebase Console/Api to send the notifications. Maybe this is a hint?

Forgot to mention the minSDK and targetSDK.

minSdkVersion 14

targetSdkVersion 23

compileSdkVersion 23

Comment: can you tell me what is `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: Is your app running on Lollipop or above? And you can change the Notification Icon with this API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setColor(int)