# firebase messaging Android issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase messaging for both my android and iOS app. I am making the push with a POST request to fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and I used to have a body with the data{}. unfortunately, this showed the icon only for android but on iOS, this notification wouldn't even show up. I now switched it to a body with something like 
[image]

This POST call showed the logo but it did not work at all on iOS devices.
[image]

and now this works on iOS and android. Unfortunately however, the android icon now doesn't show and it looks like this. [image]

How could I fix this issue with android while retaining this type of body in the POST request?

Comment: Provide code, please. Where is this notification being created? You have to set the image you want there.

Comment: The notification is being made by our system when an action completes. This isn't on the app side, this is on a piece of hardware that makes this POST request. I will add an image of the POST call that i am making in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to set targetSdkVersion to 20 (or less) in your app's build.gradle.

Otherwise you need to redesign your icon to conform with lollipop and above icon specifications.

see [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)