# Don't set the notification icon

Tags: android, notifications

Instead of the icons I want to set, always displayed the standard ic_launcher. Tried and vector images, and a png.

What's wrong?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notifADBStarted = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.server_is_active))
        .setContentText("adb connect" + " " + usersIP.getIpAddress())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_wifi_tethering_white_24dp)
        .setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.server_is_active))
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_wifi_tethering_black_24dp))
        .setContentIntent(pIntent);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    notifADBStarted.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
}
notificationManager.notify(0, notifADBStarted.build());
```

Comment: what is your Android version...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 6.0.1

Comment: there is issue in Seticon method in latest version of Android see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: Also check wheather your Custom Notification is called or not...if notification is System generated then it will show ic_launcher always