# Notification icon turns white in Android L

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

1) MarshMallow Notification Icon(Tablet)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrFia.png)

2) MarshMallow Notification Icon(SmartPhone)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u02x4.png)

When loading a resource with the `setSmallIcon` method, the tablet loads normally,
The smartphone is loaded with a white icon.

The smartphone and tablet OS are the same Android 6 (MarshMallow).

I want the icon to appear as an icon of the image I put in, not the material design, even on Android 5 OS or later.

Help Me.

Comment: Check [here](https://material.io/icons/)

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop