# Notification bar icon turns white on tablet

Tags: android, notifications

[image]

I have a issue with icons notification who are display in white square only on tablet.

I am aware of new recommendations since android 5 (and find nice post about it : [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop))

But my client send me a screenshot with white square notification and another one with full color.

Do you have an idea to understand the problem ?

I have a correctly full color (like my apps icon) on smartphone, only show in white with tablet.

Comment: Asks your designer to provide the image with transparent background. It should solve your problem

Comment: @TrickySolutions That's what I could do but my client's logo look pretty ugly with only 2 colors and I still want to understand WHY it works with smartphone but not on tablet (my logo is present in hdpi to xxhdpi)