# Notification Icon showing white on lollipop and above devices

Tags: android, firebase, icons, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for push notification and below is my code for generating a notification:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Notification.Builder notification;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notification = new Notification.Builder(this);
} else {
    notification = new Notification.Builder(this);
    notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sysTransparent));
}

notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText("This is notification body")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
```

and this is the output:[image]

Does anyone know how to remove the excess white?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

> try this one, it works for me

```
protected void displayNotification(Context context, String[] strContent) {
        try {
            int numMessages = 0;

            /* Invoking the default notification service */
            NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            mBuilder.setContentTitle("New "+strContent[0].trim());
            mBuilder.setContentText("You've received new "+strContent[0].trim());
            mBuilder.setTicker("New "+strContent[0].trim()+" Alert!");
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary));
            mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});         

            mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
         mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            String[] events = new String[strContent.length-1];
            for(int i=0; i<strContent.length-1; i++){
                events[i] = new String(strContent[i+1].trim());
            }

            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("New "+strContent[0].trim()+" received!");

            for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
            }

            mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

            /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);


            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);

            /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
            mNotificationManager.notify(9999, mBuilder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I try this but still showing the same white icon for lollipop and above devices.