# Firebase Cloud Messaging: How to set the notification icon on android?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having trouble setting the notification icon on android studio.

I set up the drawable folder like so:

[image]

And I've also set the default icon in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

> ```
>   <meta-data
>     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
>     android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
> ```

And here I'm setting the icon field to `notification_icon`: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json (p.s. I'm aware that's GCM, but it works. I'm receiving the notification with everything besides the icon)

What am I missing? All I see is a white square inside a grey circle.

This is my backend code: `Pushex.push(%{title: user.name, body: "message goes here", badge: 1, sound: "default", icon: "notification_icon"}, to: user.fcm_token, using: :gcm)` (https://github.com/tuvistavie/pushex)

Comment: Where would I put that line?

Comment: Could you include your sample payload (pretty printed)? You mentioned you were using `notification_icon`, but in the docs it should just be `icon`. Or is it just the way you set it in your code?

Comment: @AL updated with my backend call

Comment: @Edmund Where is the <meta-data ../> part in you AndroidManifest file?
It should be in this hierarchy.
<application>
  <meta-data .... />
... </application>

Comment: @Mann just figured it out after hours... look at my answer below

Comment: Hi, can you please explain your drawable folder because your photo link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

I am using the [FCM plugin](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated) and here is what worked for me (September 2019):

1. In **config.xml** (yourapp/config.xml)
   Add the following to the  tag at the end
   `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

It should look something like this now:

`<widget id="com.mydomain.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Or simply, copy the above line, replace the value of widget id, with your own.

2. In the same **config.xml** file:
   Just before the  tag corresponding to , add this:

```
<config-file parent="/manifest/application/" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/fcm_push_icon" />
</config-file>
```

3. Visit the following link:
   [Notification Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=fcm_push_icon)

Upload a **White version (single color) of your logo on a Transparent background**. If you upload a colored version, you will get a dark gray icon, which would look nasty. If you don't have a white version of your logo, get it designed. Leave the rest of the settings as they are. For the Name textbox value, enter: **fcm_push_icon**. Then click on the Blue colored round shaped button to download the zip file.

4. Unzip the zip file that you just downloaded it the above step and extract its contents to a folder. You will notice that it contains a **res** folder. If you open this folder, it will contain other folders with the following names:

   - drawable-hdpi
   - drawable-mdpi
   - drawable-xhdpi
   - drawable-xxhdpi
   - drawable-xxxhdpi

Each of those folders will contain a PNG icon by the name "fcm_push_icon.png". The only difference between the icons in those different folders is their size.

5. Open the following file path in your app (If it doesn't exist, create it as shown below):

`yourApp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res`

Simply copy all the 5 folders listed in in the point 4 above, to the location shown just above i.e. into the **res** folder i.e. into `yourApp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res`

That's it! Now just build your app. Whenever you receive a notification, you will see your app icon in the notifications (at least on Android).

***If anyone has figured out how to make colored icons appear in the Android notifications, please share your solution.***

Comment: @un.spike Thank you for your confirmation. Appreciate it. Glad to hear it works for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it... this is so stupid. Was inspired by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28387744/1555312

I made my notification icon my app icon:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

And then the magic line in `android/app/build.gradle`...

```
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 20 // this has to be < 21
    ...
}
```

Hope I save hours of someone else's life

Comment: While this works you really don't need to go back to level 20. If you want to use 21 and above, which is common, you need to create a notification icon that is white with transparent background to work. Your launcher icon should not be reused as it is full color and will show up as just a white square.

Comment: It is a harmful advice for modern applications. Don't downgrade target SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Check this code. It may help you.

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
            private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {       
                Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClass.class);
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), NotificationID.getID(), intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body")))
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(NotificationID.getID(), notificationBuilder.build());
            }
            private int getNotificationIcon() {
                boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
                //If the build version is higher than kitkat we need to create Silhouette icon. 
                return useWhiteIcon ? R.mipmap.ic_notification : R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            }

            public static class NotificationID {
                private static final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);

                public static int getID() {
                    return c.incrementAndGet();
                }
            }
        }
```

If the build version is higher than kitkat we need to create Silhouette icon. For that online tool is available 
        Refer:https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html

Answer (score 3):

With SDK 9.8.0 however, you can override the default! In your AndroidManifest.xml you can set the following fields to customise the icon and color:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/google_blue" />
```

and

```
<manifest>
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- Add your meta-data here-->

    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: I already have that (it's in my question): ```<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />```

Comment: ```Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"'```