# Notification Colour Icon Not Visible in Lollipop,It Show only a White background

Tags: android, notifications

How to visible notification icon without reduce target sdk version to 20 from >20.
my Notification Icon is colour icon,not Transparent. I used below Code but its not working In case of Lollipop.It showing only White background.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_colour);
} else { 
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_colour);
}
```

Comment: What is your R.drawable.icon_colour? Can you show it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: Potapov Anton ...My icon is a png file

Answer (score 0):

> Android Lollipop notification icons are meant to be displayed in white
>   style.

[There is a documentation for "Android 5.0 behavior changes"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html)

> Notifications are drawn in dark text on white backgrounds (or very
>   light) to match the new widgets of the design material.

This documentation also suggests that you use a color that will be displayed behind the (white) notification icon, where it says:

> Use setColor () to set a highlight color in a circle behind the icon
>   image.

Your solution should be used different rules for each Android version, which you are already using with `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`

Try updating your answer with that:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_no_colour);
    build.setColor(R.color.icon_background_color);
} else { 
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_colour);
}
```

[setColor() documentantion](http://android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT%20%3E=%20Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)