# Empty Image was showing in my Notification Bar

Tags: android, image, notifications

I am working in an android app Notifications . I am able to get the Notifications perfectly but Unable to display an image on Notification. The Notification was as shown in the below .
[image]

this is my Build.gradle File

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ex.myfile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
```

I followed the below Dimentions

24 × 24 (mdpi)

36 × 36 (hdpi)

48 × 48 (xhdpi)

72 × 72 (xxhdpi)

96 × 96 (xxxhdpi)

and My Code was

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (jsonobj.has("streamURL")) {
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(jsonobj.getString("userName") + " is LiveNow");
        } else if ((jsonobj.has("title") && (jsonobj.has("message")))) {
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(allFilesDataModel.getFileTitle() + " " + allFilesDataModel.getMessage());
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("new Video was Uploaded To YouTube");
        }

        // notificationBuilder.setContentText("" + allFilesDataModel.getFileApprovedOrDenied());
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
        NOTIFICATION_ID++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop). You'll need to use two different icons for API >= 21.

in `setSmallIcon()` you'll need to pass proper icon for API >= 21

Comment: I found that we have to use transparent Notification Image for the notification. I  used transparency in my image background but again I got the same white color as outline instead of my Original notification's  Icon Outline which is red color