# How to send notification from IntentService in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin, intentservice

I am new to android development and I want to send a notification from the IntentService when the device enters in any specific geofence which is setted by the user. I had written the below code for sending a notification.

```
class GeofenceIntentService : IntentService("GeofenceIntentService") {

var notId: Int = 15452
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    var geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
    if(geofencingEvent.hasError())
    {
        Log.e("JK-->>","geofencingError -->> "+geofencingEvent.hasError())
        return
    }

    var geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
    {
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,0,Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Entered In Geofence!").setContentText("Click here for return to app!!").setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build()

        var notiManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notId = notId + 1
        notiManager.notify(notId,notification)

        Log.e("JK-->>", "Entered in geofence")
    }
    else if(geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    {
        var notiBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Entered In Geofence").setContentText("Click Here for return to app!").build()
        var notiManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        var intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        notiBuilder.contentIntent = pendingIntent
        notId = notId + 1
        notiManager.notify(notId,notiBuilder)

        Log.e("JK-->>", "Entered in geofence")
        Log.e("JK-->>", "Exit from geofence")
    }
}}
```

I had also checked that my service is called when the device enters or exit from geofence by putting debug points. No Object gets null value and everything goes fine but the notification does not receive.
How can I do??

Comment: try adding `.setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationDrawableResource)`

Comment: setAutoCancel(true) is already added. Let me try using setSmallIcon().

Comment: i used that as a hint :P

Comment: Yes! your hint work bro! thanks!! but can you explain to me why it doesn't take default icon for notification and why need to set it explicitly? @pavneet Singh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add icon in your notification otherwise your notification will be triggered but won't be displayed on the status bar.

But why? Because it is one of the minimum requirement by android OS to display notification under [`Required notification contents`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required)

**A Notification object must contain the following**:

> `A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()`.
>
> A title, set by setContentTitle().
>
> Detail text, set by setContentText().
>
> On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, a valid notification channel ID, set by setChannelId() or provided in the NotificationCompat.Builder constructor when creating a channel.

```
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext)
                   .setAutoCancel(true)
                   .setContentTitle("Entered In Geofence!")
                   .setContentText("Click here for return to app!!")
                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationDra‌​wableResource)
                   // add ^^^^^^^
                   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build()
```

Note : As per lollipop standard , your notification icon should be transparent and you can use `setColor` to set background color but you have to put a check to call `setColor` as per android OS

[`Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: Ohk. Thanks but now i receive notification but when i click on that then nothing happens. It should start my MainActivity.

Comment: Probably because you create a pending intent for a service and not for an activity.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani i guess that is due using same id for `getActivity` and `getService` with `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to effect changes in already displayed notification (which starts service) so try changing id  `PendingIntent.getActivity(this,10,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`

Comment: Nice Explaination @Pavneet_Singh +1

Comment: should i generate new id every time when i create PendingIntent Object or i can use same id every time for entering in geofence and another id at time of exiting from geofence?

Comment: since you want two actions so either you can have two different notification with different ids or you can try using  [FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT) and @VikasTiwari thanks for appreciation

Comment: i tried both solutions but it's not working.@pavneet_singh

Comment: is your `MainActivity` is service as well as activity? because in both cases you are using `MainActivity` for service and activity both , i guess they should be different

Comment: Its my pleasure @Pavneet_Singh we beginner get to learn from you :)

Comment: can't get it. My MainActivity is Activity and GeofenceIntentService is service and i don't have any service named MainActivity in my whole project.

Comment: can you explain me in brief please? @pavneet_singh

Comment: @JaydipKalkani then change `PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,0,Intent` to `PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext,0,Intent`

Comment: yes!! I just got it!! It Works! Thank you very much! @Pavneet_singh

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding and @VikasTiwari that's what SO community is all about , we learn from each other :)