# Notification background with grey square

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When the notif is displayed, the icon is showed. But when I expand the notification menu, it's a grey icon.

My manifest :

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@android:color/transparent" />
```

For exemple, here in this screenshot, the icon is displayed (the green one) :

[image]

But then :

[image]

Comment: It is turning it into gray scale, based on alpha/colour. Since your entire image has no alpha, it is creating a gray square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the android above lollipop OS devices, the notification Icon background color should be grey and should follow the notification icon guidelines provided by android.

If you run the same application in the KitKat the existing works fine.

Anyhow there is a solution, 
[Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)
But it will not work when your app is in closed state.

Check with the below link for icon design guidelines.

[Reference web address. Click here for more Info](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)

Answer (score 2):

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), notificationId+"")
            .setContentTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message.getAlert())
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_transparent);
    } else {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_color);
    }
```

used two notification icon

1) Transparent background.   Example icon : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlEzp.png

2) Color  (generally use  'ic_launcher_icon')