# Push notification white square icon

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, pushwoosh

I'm using pushwoosh for push notification service.
according to the Android documentation I've used a white icon for notification.
but on some devices, I see white square again.

on other hand,s I've used a colored icon and I see the colored notification.
why on some devices I can use a colored icon, and on other, I always see the white icon?

Comment: Which devices and which Android version are the problematic ones? Since Android 6, you need to provide a white icon, but some other manufacturers doesn't implement this restriction, so you could show a colored icon.

Comment: please share your notification usage by code

Comment: @Marc Device that shown white icon is asus zenfon android 6.1 and another that shown colored is samsun j7 android 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS version it happens.You may have observed it is only happening in low version of OS's like jellybean,kitkat.

I don't think this will happen in lollipop or marshmallow and above OS versions.

Comment: Device that shown white icon is asus zenfon android 6.1 and another that shown colored is samsun j7 android 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Guidelines for icon designing, otherwise it will be in white box for some Android versions. You can look here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar. Based on this you should use .png image and only white and grey color for icons.

Comment: Device that shown white icon is asus zenfon android 6.1 and another that shown colored is samsun j7 android 6.1

Comment: I had the similar problem, Google suggest to change the icon based on the guidelines. So you can avoid the problem competitively.

Comment: Also you can look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop