# How to change expo push notification icon and point to a specific screen when app is closed

Tags: expo

The problem I am having is that

- push notifications received from expo notification service always have the expo icon instead of the one specified (my app's icon),
- and when clicked point to the expo client instead of the standalone app

Local scheduled notification show the app icon as intended

Questions:

1. How can I change the remote notification icon to a custom one and
2. point to a specific path/screen in the standalone app instead of the expo client?

Image description:
Top notification shows a local scheduled notification and bottom the push notification using the expo push notification service

[image: Top notification shows a local scheduled notification and bottom the push notification using the expo push notification service]

my app.json:

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "Vevivo",
    "slug": "Vevivo",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "34.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.2.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/AppIcon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#E6762F",
    "scheme": "vevivo",
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.vevivo.vevivo"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.vevivo.vevivo",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 5
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "https://vevivo-images-bucket-develop.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/common/logo96Gray.png",
```

}

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to see your notification icon in iOS so your app should be standalone app.

> ExpoKit: To change the notification icon, edit or replace the shell_notification_icon.png files in android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-. On iOS, notification icons are the same as the app icon. All other properties are set at runtime.

For build for standalone app follows this [guide](https://docs.expo.dev/classic/building-standalone-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Run in managed app (not bare - Expo Client):

try push the icon to local assets:

```
expo": {
    ....
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/logo96Gray.png"
    },
```

Comment: Hi, does this work in development or only in production?

Answer (score 0):

due to the time it has already resolved, but for future doubts I believe I can help, your code is right but you seem to be using the expo and not the generated application, try to generate a standalone version that the notifications should appear normally, also check the image size to avoid problems, check out this answer for that.

[types of images for push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607739/expo-standalone-app-notification-icons-dont-show-up-show-up)

Comment: What does stand alone mean? This is ejecting expo?