# Expo React Native iOS push notifications - How to change the icon

Tags: react-native, expo

I have my Expo React Native - Stand Alone app (Published to Test Flight) and I still seeing the Expo icon on the push notifications:

[image]

This is my app.json

```
{
    "expo": {
      "name": "test-answers",
      "slug": "test-answers",
      "version": "1.0.6",
      "orientation": "portrait",
      "icon": "./assets/images/appicon-1024.png",
      "scheme": "myapp",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "notification":{
        "icon":"./assets/images/push-notification-icon-expo.png",
        "color": "#311b92",
        "androidMode": "default",
        "androidCollapsedTitle": "Updates from Test Answers",
        "iosDisplayInForeground": true
     },
      "updates": {
        "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
      },
      "assetBundlePatterns": [
        "**/*"
      ],
      "platforms" :[
        "ios",
        "android"
      ],
      "ios": {
        "icon": "./assets/images/appicon-1024.png",
        "usesAppleSignIn": true,
        "supportsTablet": true,
        "bundleIdentifier": "com.test.test",
        "config": {
          "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-111222~111222",
          "googleMobileAdsAutoInit" : true
        },
        "googleServicesFile": "./assets/GoogleService-Info.plist",
        "buildNumber": "1.0.6"
      },
      "android": {
        "adaptiveIcon": {
          "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
          "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "config": {
          "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-111222~111222",
          "googleMobileAdsAutoInit" : true
        },
        "googleServicesFile": "./assets/google-services.json",
        "package": "com.test.test",
        "versionCode": 1
      },
      "web": {
        "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png",
        "config": {
          "firebase": {
            "apiKey": "abc123",
            "measurementId": "G-123abc"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

> Any clue?

Comment: Which service are you using to send push notifications to the device? FCM?

Comment: Also, let us know if you are using expo classic builder or eas builder! Also check if this was helpful https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/remove-alpha-channel.md

Comment: Im using Expo Push Notiticarion service. Yes I’m using EAS Builder @RajendranNadar