# Firebase Notification is grey flutter

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to my Flutter app. It works fine but my app icon notification is grey on the Google Pixel XL. I can see the outline,  but for some reason, it's still grey. I've read in different articles that it has to do with the Android SDK level, but the minSdkVersion in Flutter is already 16 (less than 21) so I don't understand why the color won't show on.

So is it possible to show my app icon for notifications with the color?

--Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of icon are you talking about? The icon on the tray bar or the icon on the notification you see on lock/swiped down screen?

Comment: The icon on the notification you see on lock/swiped down screen.

Comment: It's also bw with the Flutter Icon

Comment: Yeah, I added a comment to it.

Comment: Hey there ^^. Did you eventually have your colored notification icon?

Comment: Hello, not yet. I will try it out in a couple of days since I'm finishing another part of the app right now. (The deadline is approaching --haha) :). But as soon as I try it out, I will let you know! --Thanks

Comment: Did you reach your deadline? Any news?

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking up. I did reach my deadline. A lot of our users actually like the slick grey icon so we decided to just keep it that way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging#custom-default-color) you can read:

> **Customize default notification**
>
> **Custom default icon**
>
> Setting a custom default icon allows you to specify what icon is used
>   for notification messages if no icon is set in the notification
>   payload. Also use the custom default icon to set the icon used by
>   notification messages sent from the Firebase console. ***If no custom
>   default icon is set and no icon is set in the notification payload,
>   the application icon (rendered in white) is used.***
>
> **Custom default Color**
>
> You can also define what color is used with your notification.
>   Different android versions use this settings in different ways:
>   Android < N use this as background color for the icon. Android >= N
>   use this to color the icon and the app name.

Try putting that in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message.  -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

You can find more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

You also need to have your `colorAccent` define. You can create a `colors.xml` file in your res folder like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorAccent">#E91E63</color>
</resources>
```

In this folder: `/android/app/src/main/res/values`

Also the icon must be in the `drawable` folder.

But remember that this icon must be `white` with a *transparent background*.

For some type of [icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) to be colored you need on some device sets `meta-tags` you already added in yuor `AndroidManifest.xml` and your icon must follow some specifications (must be white in a transparent background). You can try to generate one [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit). Give it a try. Remember to put it on drawable folder and update the manifest `meta-tag` icon name.

Read also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop) that stengthens up what I've said here.

I've tried on the Pixel 2 emulator running API level 27:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting a `error: resource color/colorAccent (aka com.package.package:color/colorAccent) not found` error. Where do I add the color resource?

Comment: I'l looking at Stack Overflow's notification icon. It's also greyed out. Maybe this is how it's supposed to be on newer versions of Android? But then again, snapchat, FB and others have color.

Comment: @PrinceHodonou Btw, if you didn't have colorAccent defined you get that error. If you use AS. Give it a try. I'll update my answer so that you can see what to do.

Comment: I've tried it as such :
`<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
            
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />`

It compiles and everything, but the icon is still grey. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @PrinceHodonou so strange. Unfortunately I'm not so lucky to have a Pixel XL to give it a try ^_^. On different devices do you see the icon in true colors or alway in bw? May I ask you if you set the icon onto notification JSON payload or not? By now all my trials with flutter FCM, without setting the icon in JSON payload, give me the flutter icon in bright colors on my devices.

Comment: Haha, I've ran the app on an older Android device and the icon is in color. No, I didn't set the icon in my payload. I didn't even know you can do that haha. So when you work with FCM, the icons are all in colors? This is very weird indeed. :)

Comment: @PrinceHodonou for these [icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) to be colored you need on some device sets meta-tags you already added in yuor manifest.xml and your icon must follow some specifications. You can try to generate one [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit). Give it a try. Remember to put it on drawable folder and update the manifest meta-tag. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. What finally did it for me was to use the icon generator. My normal icon would not work, and I actually needed to remove the background from it for it to even show up in the generator. No wonder it kept showing up as grey/white.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is regarding Firebase notification but since on searching the same for local_notifiction grey icon error this post came ...so finally I was able to find the solution to that(in my case icons work fine in debug mode but on building apk icons become grey boxes)

Solution:-
in **Android/app/src/main/res** create a new directory named **raw** and in that directory add a file named **keep.xml**  and copy paste the following:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*" />
```

Comment: You literally made my day and saved me a day of searching. But just out of curiosity how did you figure this out?

Comment: just lot of searching and hit and trials. And when I find the answer I just get back to this question so that no one else has to face the same. Thanks @techpool for appreciation,

Comment: Why this doesn't work with "tools:keep="@mipmap/*"" ?

Answer (score 7):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Create a transparent and white notification icon (you can use the following tool: AndroidAssetStudio )

Download the zip folder, unzip and you'll see it contains a res folder with different drawable folders. Copy and paste the contents of the res folder in "android\app\src\main\res" path

[image: Folder Structure]

2. Then open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following lines to it:

ic_stat_calendar_today is the name of my notification icon. And each of the drawable folders that have been pasted contain a different size of icon with the same name.

[image: Android Manifest]

3. If you want to change the color of the icon then check the above image. Add the metadata tag after the notification icon tag
4. Go to "android\app\src\main\res\values" and add a colors.xml file

[image: colors.xml]

```
<color name="colorAccent">#00FF00</color>
```

I have shared this answer in the following Github chain as well- [Solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-622268132).

Answer (score 3):

Majority are making one single problem.

They are placing the meta tags

```
<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
           android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Inside the  tags while they should be placing it above  and inside the <application tag
f.e.

`````
    package="xxxx">
   <application
        android:label="xxxx"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
           android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <activity
            android:name="xxxx"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
                android:value="true" />
            <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="flutterstripe" android:host="safepay" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="xxxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
```` </manifest>


Also its important to create separate file colors.xml and include color of your choice.
```` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="splash_color">#00ABC8</color>
 </resources>



Rebuild app (close and run again)

and it will work.
`````

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still having problems after adding the:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" … />
```

Please make sure you are adding it directly under `<application/>` tag, instead of an `<activity/>` tag, in the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Here is my finding.

1. Use **AndroidAssetStudio** to generate notification icon.
2. Try putting that in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message.  -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Note: Above changes should be below `<application>` not in `<activity>`.

3. Also check the minSdkVersion. When i use `minSdkVersion 20` it was not working and when i set to `minSdkVersion 21` it was work fine.

Answer (score 0):

add this in android/app/build.gradle in section "buildTypes" if not show icon only in release:

shrinkResources false

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false  //  <------------

    }
}
```