# How do I change the color of the push notification icon in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send a push notification with firebase to my Android device, the icon is just a gray square without any color, so how do I change that so the icon has some color? Do I have to change that in my cloud function, do I have to change that in my flutter code, or do I have to change that in my Android Manifest file?

Comment: Look also at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056662/firebase-notification-is-grey-flutter/54056825#54056825)