# android notification setSmallIcon not work after 5.0

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to use **setSmallIcon()** to set the notification's statusbar icon, my icon is completely white,no other color,but it's not working. The icon is just the system default one, I don't know how to solve it.Does the size matter? I have tried 16*16dp 32*32dp 48*48dp,and it's useless.

Comment: This SO post may help you if you are still struggling with this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188689/why-do-icons-set-with-notification-builder-setsmallicon-in-android-lollipop-show

Comment: Thx.It's my cellphone's problem.